# How can I absolutely position jQuery draggables and still make them move correctly for droppable to work? (a problem just with IE)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I've read lots of articles and tried everything I can think of, but I can't manage all three: position a draggable object, make it move correctly and get the droppable object to recognize it. When I change the code, I manage every time to do one or two of them, but never all of them together, and I need them all.

Here is some code:

In the .aspx:

```
<table id="tblAll" border="1" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
        <tr dir="ltr" id="trAreas">
            <td id="tdAreas" colspan="2"><asp:Xml ID="xmlAreas" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trMain">
            <td id="tdButtons" style="width:75px;">
                <div id="droppable">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgTrash" ImageUrl="~/Images/Trash.png" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="tdMain" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="divMain" Width="700px" Height="400px" runat="server" CssClass="MainBackground"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Xml ID="xmlAreaTables" runat="server" />  
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

In the xsl file, where I bring the elementes from the DB and postion them on the page:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Tables/Table">
      <div class="test" id="divTable_{@ObjectID}" style="position: absolute; top:{@RowID}px; right:{@ColID}px;">
        <img id="img_{@ObjectID}" src="{@ImageURL}"/>
      </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidTypeID_{@ObjectID}" value="{@ObjectTypeID}" />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

And last the .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").draggable({});
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) 
              {
                alert("fgsdfgtd");
              }
    });      
});
```

I've tried also:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Tables/Table">
  <div class="test" style="position: absolute;">
    <div class="test1" id="divTable_{@ObjectID}" style="top:{@RowID}px; right:{@ColID}px;">
      <img id="img_{@ObjectID}" src="{@ImageURL}"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="hidTypeID_{@ObjectID}" value="{@ObjectTypeID}" />
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And that is the closest one yet, but that is putting all the elements in one place in the top right corner of the main div, from there i can do any thing i want, but the problem is that they are not positioned in the original places and that is a huge problem (i did alert on the style for each one and they still getting the right position but not showing in the right place)...

I've tried many versions of `di`v and where to put the `style="position: absolute;"` and the position of the elements. I need to bring them from the DB and position them dynamically on the page and I need them to drag freely (not just up an down one the same line) and to be recognized when being dropped to the trash. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 10x, But i wasn't aiming for the title of the year aword LOL, just looking for the solution :-) and Matt, 10x for the edit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem....

Again, dir="rtl" was the problem....IE8 doesn't like RTL too much i guess, i had (and probably will have) lots of problems with that....:-)